# Wildcard domains in Ubuntu 14.14

Tags: apache, configuration, wildcard-subdomain

I have one SSL domain on ubuntu VPS and I want all subdomains to point to general example.com for example : site1.example.com, site2.example.com to load code from example.com.

I know how this can be done with virtual hosts, but I don't want every time to add new virtual hosts and restart the apache.

So I read for 'Willcard domains', but I can`t setup it.Also read I must add this o virtual host definition 'ServerAlias *.example.com' and some where I must add zone record or somethin like this.

```
<VirtualHost IP:443>

VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public/

SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite 
SSLCertificateFile 
SSLCertificateKeyFile 
SSLCertificateChainFile 

ServerAlias *.example.com
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
</VirtualHost>
```

I am junior in web servers, so any detailed steps will help.

Answer (score 1):

*First, you have to own a wildcard SSL certificate and have it installed. They are not the same as a standard SSL certificate. They are quite a bit more expensive, for one. You can create a self-signed one, but that is only good for testing with.*

**Correction, I misunderstood. You do not need a wildcard SSL if you are redirecting all the subdomains to the parent. You only need it if you want unique subdomains with SSL as well.**

Next you have already, the ServerAlias *.example.com

Last, for each subdomain you need to configure a CNAME DNS record to point the subdomain to the parent example.com. I strongly suggest you research this thoroughly before you start trying to make changes to your DNS settings. Some changes can stick for quite a while, even after you change them again. I don't know what you use to manage your DNS so I can't offer specifics, nor do I encourage you to make such changes if you aren't comfortable with what you are doing. You could break your website DNS for days at a time. That said, it's not actually very difficult as long as you don't mess with any of the existing stuff.

In CPanel, I can configure a DNS record for a wildcard subdomain like..

- Name: subdomain.example.com.
- TTL: 14400
- Type: CNAME
- Record: example.com

Comment: I have installed webmin , I think there I can configure this *.example.com record. But I dont know how.

Comment: How to add this type of records and where is this zone file or if I can do this in webmin interface.

Comment: If you have a proper webhost, they probably already have a DNS manager. You need to use that one. Setting up your own would only be if your are making your own webserver. If you are trying to setup subdomains for your website listed in your profile at microdesign-web.com then you already have CPanel. There is a DNS Zone Editor Tool in there. microdesign-web.com/cpanel

Comment: No it is not, that is for my client on VPS hosting and there is only webmin installed. I dont have problems with cPanels, but this here is another think :)

Comment: Please help me , where I can add this zone record.

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with Webmin. It's also a different question than what you originally asked. I suggest you ask a new question about how to setup webmin and create a DNS zone record. I suspect that you don't actually need it, but that is better discussed in the forums, not questions and answers.

Comment: I think there is no matter how I will add this record via webmin or in server terminal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin x@xxx.org
ServerAlias  *.yourdomain.net
#ServerName could be any non-exist sub-domain 
ServerName   blabla.bla.yourdomain.net

ServerSignature On
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile path_of_your_cert
SSLCertificateKeyFile path_of_your_key
SSLCACertificateFile path_of_your_intermediate_cert
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm
DocumentRoot /yourWebRoot

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
# Disable access to domains like "a.b.yourdomain.net"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.yourdomain\.net$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=502,L]
# Rewrite sub.yourdomain.net to folder /yourWebRoot/sub
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.yourdomain\.net$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /yourWebRoot/${lowercase:%1}/$1
RewriteRule (.*)/icons/(.*) /usr/share/apache2/icons/$2 [L]

DirectoryIndex  index.php index.htm index.html

</VirtualHost>
```

If you want your sub-domain all goes to the same document-root folder, remove all those rewrite in my sample conf.

ServerName is a must-have in your conf file

If you do not have a wildcard ssl(70$-1000$ USD/year), use rewrite to redirect all other domain to the main domain. (but this may caused a cookie/postdata leakage)

Comment: This is a simpler solution that fakes it rather than messing with DNS, but the rewrites redirect subdomains to sub folders which is not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: This coase to ' Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration '

Comment: my mod_rewrite is enabled , without mod_rewrite I cant run Laravel, but @FyzzyLogic is right I dont need from this solution that you offer me